Not Able to create new Sitecore XM Cloud Project - Error - Choose Project
The Problem:
Trying to connect your XM Cloud account (TEST-XM-CLOUD-POC) to your DevOps account through the XM Cloud interface.
When selecting a project in the "Choose Project" dropdown, it's blank, and receive a CORS error in the console (#3).
Any information to resolve this issue helps.

#2 - CHECKED IN THE AZURE DEVOPS

#3 - CORS Error in Console (when we select the project drop down)


It seems due to CORS setting enabled on your Azure Devops. You can try adding deploy.sitecorecloud.io url inside the CORS setting on the Azure Devops.

I don't see any such CORS in azure DevOps, any additional references could help..

Have you created a support ticket?

Yes, raised sitecore ticket, Sitecore say check with the Azure DevOps. This was working last week, then stopped working.

The above issue might be occuring due to the CORS policy confgured inside Azure Devops. You can add the above deploy.sitecorecloud.io url inside that setting to resolve this.
CORS setting for the Azure Devops can be found by navigating as below.

Access Organizational Setting after logging to https://dev.azure.com. It is situated at the bottom left corner.

Navigate to Policies tab: In the left sidebar, under Security, click on Policies.

Scroll down to find the Application Connection Policies section. Add the above domain inside Authorized OAuth domains or Third-party application access via OAuth setting.



You can add Sitecore deploy url in the above OAuth Authorized Domain setting and save the changes.
Hope this helps!!!

This is fantastic, this worked.

Glad to hear that...Thank you @Sivalingaamorthy
